# How to arrange vectors in a circle so as to minimize the resultant?

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, permutations, vectors

Sorry for the vague language, but I want to arrange weights in a circle so as to minimize the resultant moment. The axis of rotation is perpendicular to the plane in which the weights lie, and the weights have to be on the circumference of the circle, hence they all must be equidistant from the axis of rotation and have to be placed at regular angular intervals of $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{n}$. The radius of the circle is r and the weights are $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$, ... , $w_n$.

I tried two approaches but reached dead ends:

1. First, I tried to minimize the x and y components of the resultant separately. But I couldn't figure out how to minimize this sum by interchanging the coefficients:

   $V_x$ = $rw_1\cos0$ + $rw_2\cdot\cos\theta$ + $rw_3\cdot\cos2\theta$ + .... + $rw_n\cdot\cos(n-1)\theta$

   $V_y$ = $rw_1\sin0$ + $rw_2\cdot\sin\theta$ + $rw_3\cdot\sin2\theta$ + .... + $rw_n\cdot\sin(n-1)\theta$
2. I tried to see the problem as a sum of complex numbers with different magnitudes arranged in a circle. But, then again I couldn't find any way to minimize their sum by interchanging their arguments.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Without weights conditions the problem is undefined. Suppose you put all weights in the intersection of the circle with the axis of inertia, then the moment is $0$.

Comment: I want to place all the weights at the circumference of the circle, equal angular distance apart. As for the values of the weights, I understand that the solution would not be defined. But, I want to know how to approach the problem, given the weights. Say, I have 7 weights valued 10, 11, 15, 16, 13, 18 and 20 kgs. How do I approach it, then?

Comment: I think you are asking about a combinatorial problem where you are trying to find the optimum of $(n-1)!$ arrangements of weights around a circle, right?

Comment: Yes, but that would take a lot of time to compute even if n is a small number like 50. So, is there a better way to approach this? I was thinking that if n is even, then I could just arrange all the weights in ascending order and then put consecutive weights opposite to each other. The only problem with this is I don't know whether this is the optimum arrangement.

Comment: If the axis of rotation is in the same plane as the circle, then put heavier weights nearer the axis, and lighter weights far from it.

Comment: This isn’t straightforward.  Consider you have 3 values of $X$ which is much greater than $n-3$ values of $Y$. The optimal solution is a equidistribution of $X$ about the circle. If you reduce the problem to a line, I wonder if this has been done before. Let me look.

Comment: If you look at the 1-d case, such as a projection of the weights at a certain angle onto a line, this is an assignment problem, for which there are polynomial time solutions. I believe then that the 2-d case is a multidimensional assignment problem, for which there are heuristics. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10878-012-9554-z One idea I had was to solve the problem at some initial projection $\theta_0$ and then slowly “turn the circle” by $2\pi \over n$. And continue applying the linear assignment problem for each new projection using the prior solution as a seed...

Comment: The axis of rotation is perpendicular to the plane of the weights. Thank you for pointing this out, I have edited the question. The weights have to be on the circumference of the circle, i.e they have to be equidistant from the axis of rotation. Also, they have to be spaced at regular angles.

Comment: "Also, they have to be spaced at regular angles": you should state that clearly in the question, not in the comments! Click on `edit` in the `share cite edit follow close flag` row.

Comment: I thought it was evident from the trigonometric sum that I wrote. But, yes you are correct, I'll fix it right away.